# Error with fetching chromium with fetch command

Tags: chromium

When I try to fetch chromium with the command it gives me a whole bunch of errors and at the end says "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

After the error occurred (output bellow) I tried to add the DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN to the system environment variables but after a restart nothing happened. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Error Output:

```
[0:00:00] Started.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\metrics.py", line 301, in print_notice_and_exit
    yield
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 3495, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 3481, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 3032, in CMDsync
    ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 2026, in RunOnDeps
    work_queue.flush(revision_overrides,
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 1016, in flush
    reraise(e[0], e[1], e[2])
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 70, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_utils.py", line 1093, in run
    self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient.py", line 1005, in run
    self._got_revision = self._used_scm.RunCommand(command, options, args,
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 128, in RunCommand
    return getattr(self, command)(options, args, file_list)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 610, in update
    mirror = self._GetMirror(url, options, revision, revision_ref)
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 1060, in _GetMirror
    if not self.cache_dir:
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\gclient_scm.py", line 225, in cache_dir
    return git_cache.Mirror.GetCachePath()
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\git_cache.py", line 193, in GetCachePath
    cachepath = subprocess.check_output(
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\.cipd_bin\3.8\bin\Lib\subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\.cipd_bin\3.8\bin\Lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\.cipd_bin\3.8\bin\Lib\subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\src\depot_tools\.cipd_bin\3.8\bin\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1311, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Subprocess failed with return code 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should delete config `DEPOT_TOOLS_UPDATE` on environment.